# Need SQL query in this sample output

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sum

I have a table called DPO which is as follows:

```
Region      District    Dealer                                 Month      Dollars                     

AUS PACIFIC BRISBANE    HASTINGS (AU) - Frcst Dlr (T030  )      2014/Jan   41457419
AUS PACIFIC BRISBANE    HASTINGS (PNG) - Frcst Dlr (T040  )     2014/Jan   1585432
AUS PACIFIC BRISBANE    HASTINGS (SI) - Frcst Dlr (T090  )      2014/Jan   65444
AUS PACIFIC BRISBANE    HAWTHORNE SAMOA - Frcst Dlr (H150  )    2014/Jan   24604
```

this is the output if the delaers have more than one record it should sum up with the first record based on the month column.

for eg:

In this we can check with the dealer name  with first four letters which have more than one  records.In this  which we have 3 records so in this case it should show like this:

```
AUS PACIFIC BRISBANE    HASTINGS (AU) - Frcst Dlr (T030  )  2014/Jan   43108295

AUS PACIFIC BRISBANE    HAWTHORNE SAMOA - Frcst Dlr (H150  )    2014/Jan   24604
```

Note : Dealer name may be dynamic we can check with the first letter and we should check based on the month.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Region,District,Dealer,Month, sum(Dollars) from DPO
group by Region,District,Dealer,Month
```